# Convert current time from Unix timestamp to date format (d/m/y)

Tags: 8, datetime

In my custom module (.module) file, I am using:

```
$current_time = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
```

to get the current date... However, the date value is returned in int A Unix timestamp like: `1556582116`

I have tried so far something like:

```
$current_time = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();
$timenow = $current_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or

```
$current_time = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime('d');
```

to get only the day value... but with no success

How can I return the date value in the format of: D/M/Y like: `30/04/2019` or `30/Apr/19`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with simple PHP function. Is there any specific reason you want a drupal function ? If not then you can use PHP's `date()` function.

```
$current_time = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();

//To return 30/04/2019
$date_output = date('d/m/Y', $current_time); 

//To return 30/Apr/19
$date_output = date('d/M/y', $current_time);
```

Comment: You should use Drupal date services so the set application timezone is accounted for.

Answer (score 12):

You can format the current date using the below solutions.

**Drupal 8**:

```
//format date in 30/04/2019    
$current_time = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime('d');    
$date_today = format_date($current_time, 'custom', 'd/m/Y');    

//format date in 30/Apr/2019    
$current_timestamp = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();    
$todays_date = format_date($current_timestamp, 'custom', 'd/M/Y');
```

**Drupal 9**:

```
//format date in 30/04/2019    
$current_time = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime('d');    
$date_today = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($current_time, 'custom', 'd/m/Y');

//format date in 30/Apr/2019    
$current_timestamp = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();    
$todays_date = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($current_timestamp, 'custom', 'd/M/Y');
```